# python3 "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'OpenGL'"

Tags: python-3.x, opengl

I am running python3. I've installed OpenGL (pip install OpenGL PyOpenGL_accelerate). When I run my program (python3 opengltest1.py) I get this error:

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "opengltest1.py", line 4, in <module>
    from OpenGL.GL import *
```

Comment: what is your OS?

Comment: MacOS Sierra 10.12.6

Comment: I recommend not using pip to install PyOpenGL since it needs certain dynamic libraries that depend on the OS, looking for a native method like brew or similar.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The solution was to install OpenGL with pip3 instead of pip, i.e.

`pip3 install pyopengl`

[@eyllanesc](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6622587/eyllanesc) Thanks for the help. In following up on your suggestion, I found the solution.

Answer (score -2):

This worked for me! You must download every package with pip3. All things are separated because the syntax is different from Python 2 to Python 3.